# Automatically Creating List of Dictionaries Based Upon Two Lists of Equal Length with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, python-2.7

There are two lists:

```
customer_list = ["A7", "A8", "A9", "A10", "A11"] 
customer_index = ["8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]
```

The goal is to create the following:

```
final_list = [
{
"kind": "report#variable",
"type": "A7",
"value": line[8]}
,
{
"kind": "report#variable",
"type": "A8",
"value": line[9]}
,
{
"kind": "report#variable",
"type": "A9",
"value": line[10]}
,
{
"kind": "report#variable",
"type": "A10",
"value": line[11]}
,
{
"kind": "report#variable",
"type": "A11",
"value": line[12]}
]
```

I tried to use the following Python code, but it did not work:

```
def create_final_list(list_1, list_2):
   new_list = []
   list_prefix = '{"kind": "report#variable",'
   for num in list_1:
      for val in list_2:
         list_1_num = ' "type": ' + num 
         list_2_val = ' "value": ' + val 
         new_list.append(list_prefix + list_1_num + list_2_val)
   return new_list
```

How does one automatically create a list of Dictionaries based upon two lists of equal length and the desired format as in the above example?

Comment: you're not creating JSON, you are creating a list of dict objects.

Comment: Don't try to construct a JSON string by hand. Construct the actual object (list or dictionary) first, then let Python's built-in `json` module generate the string.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? What does _it did not work_ mean, exactly?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a JSON; but a list of dictionaries which you create in a list-comprehension with `zip()`:

```
customer_list = ["A7", "A8", "A9", "A10", "A11"] 
customer_index = ["8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]
line = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,101,11,12,13,14]  # assume this `line` list

res = [{"kind": "report#variable", "type": x, "value": line[int(y)]} for x, y in zip(customer_list, customer_index)]
```

As is in the comments, you can then do:

```
json.dumps(res)
```

..to convert `res` to a JSON string.

Comment: You can then simply write `json.dumps(res)` to convert it to a JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

Since pandas is tagged, adding another way using a dataframe and groupby:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"kind": "report#variable","type":customer_list,"value":customer_index})
final = [g.droplevel(0).to_dict() for _,g in df.stack().groupby(level=0)]
```

---

```
[{'kind': 'report#variable', 'type': 'A7', 'value': '8'},
 {'kind': 'report#variable', 'type': 'A8', 'value': '9'},
 {'kind': 'report#variable', 'type': 'A9', 'value': '10'},
 {'kind': 'report#variable', 'type': 'A10', 'value': '11'},
 {'kind': 'report#variable', 'type': 'A11', 'value': '12'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
lis = []
for i in range(len(customer_index)):
    dic = {"type" : customer_list[i], "value" : customer_index[i]}
    lis.append(dic)
```

This outputs

```
[{'type': 'A7', 'value': '8'},
 {'type': 'A8', 'value': '9'},
 {'type': 'A9', 'value': '10'},
 {'type': 'A10', 'value': '11'},
 {'type': 'A11', 'value': '12'}]
```

As in your code, if you want `line[8]`, do `line[customer_index[i]]` instead of `customer_index[i]` during dictionary initialization. Also, add 1 more key of `kind` in the dictionary, as per your requirement.

The above code works only if both `customer_list` and `customer_index` are of equal length, because the loop iterates n number of times, where n is the equal length of the list.